# PHP, echoes '1' or does not echo a specified value

Tags: php, forms

I have created a simple form validation, the PHP code when used inside the `value` attribute to auto type the form, the name and he comments display properly expect the `email` (input type="text").Have I written the code correctly or has my code has any code smells.

Edit: My question is not that, I don't receive a main it is that
I get a value of 1 or the value gets cleared of.

---

PHP code :-

```
<?php 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {
    $error="";
    if(strlen ( $_POST['name'] ) < 5 ) {
        $error = "Please type more than 4 characters<br/>";
    }

    if ( $_POST['email']="" || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
                $error.= "Please type a valid Email<br/>";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['comment']) < 4){
        $error.= "Please type more than 4 characters";
    }   

    if( !empty($error) ){
        $result = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>$error</div>";
    }   

    else {

        if( mail('jokersspirit@gmail.com','test message',"Name:".$_POST['name'].
            "Email:".$_POST['email'].
            "Comment:".$_POST['comment']) ){

            $result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Your form has been submitted</div>";
        }

        else{
            $result = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Error occurred 
            while submitting your form please try again later</div>";
        }


}

}


 ?>
```

---

HTML code : -

```
<form action="" method="post">

        <label for="name">Your Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['name'])?$_POST['name']:""; ?>">

        <label for="email">Your Email:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email']:""; ?>">

        <label for="comment">Your Comments:</label>
        <textarea name="comment" placeholder="comments" class="form-control" id="comment">
        <?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])?$_POST['comment']:""; ?>
        </textarea>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg " value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: It looks like you are using the assignment operator(=) instead of the equality operator (==) when checking the email. This causes the $_POST['email'] var to be assigned to an empty string.

Just change the part that says  `$_POST['email']=""` to `$_POST['email']==""`

Comment: sidenote: your mail may very well end up in spam and/or be marked as. No proper use of additional headers.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  nope , I use xampp and is this the efficent way of writing the code, or can my code be improved ?

Comment: See the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php and see Example #2. Plus, the way you have your POST arrays inside `mail()`, is prone to XSS injection; not good.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is here

```
if ( $_POST['email']="" || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
```

Replace it by :

```
if ( $_POST['email']=="" || !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
```

(`=` replaced by `==`)

Without it, your `$_POST['email']` is an empty string.

Comment: I am extremely sorry, I study at home and I have nobody to point it out.Thank you, I promise next time I will be very causious and never spoil this community.